# different results for php functions strpos and substr in localhost and server

Tags: php, strpos, strstr

suppose we have strings like "adjkadahsdjashd##kjhkhkjhkjhs" .
and I want to cut them to for example adjkadahsdjashd and kjhkhkjhkjhs

so I wrote this on my computer :

```
<?php
$s="508462170##dfsfgdfggf";
echo substr($s,strpos($s,"#")+2)."</br>";
echo substr($s,0,strpos($s,"#"));
?>
```

and the result is okay , but when I upload this to server , it returns me nothing .

server php version is 5.2.17

:(

Comment: Did you try it exactly like this, or is it only a part of your test file? Tried it on an appache server and it worked. Maybe you want to add an `echo "test";` to make sure that there is a result at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An shorter way for your problem would be:

```
echo implode('<br/>', explode('##', $s));
```

did this work on booth platforms.

Also `</br>`is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing the result of strpos() to narrow the problem down.